# PT lumber as the swingset frame

Tags: lumber

I am planning to build a swing set for my kids and was going to use PT lumber. I was not too much concerned with the chemical issues because my kids were now old enough. Also, the PT lumbers are cheaper than the other lumbers. Then, a friend of mine told me that PT lumber tended to get warped and twisted, especially outside when it it exposed to the sun. For this reason, he was saying that the PT lumbers would be a unsafe choice for an outdoor playset.

Is it true that the PT lumbers get warped? That was the first time I've heard. Would it be a serious issue?

Answer (score 1):

Pressure treated lumber can get warped if left out in the sun. But my experience is that if the lumber is used in an application where it is bolted onto place and secured with proper fasteners that it will work just fine. There is no doubt that certain suppliers of PT lumber are applying the treatment to the lesser grades of the wood.

Comment: It has little to do with the wood grade and much more to do with the extremely high moisture content of treated lumber. It dries in less controlled conditions than kiln-dried lumber does, and therefore warps more.

Answer (score 0):

I have built several homes and worked for Lowes for many years. At Kowes, we never had any problems with the treated lumber. Non treated, we would have to cull all of the time if it was outside in the Texas heat. Treated lumber is what I would use for your jib. Hope that info helps.

Comment: The reasons why this is true don't apply to the question. You culled a lot of standard lumber because it dried out while in your store's posession. Treated lumber is so wet that it takes much longer to dry out, and because it's mostly drying in uncontrolled conditions, it tends to warp worse than standard, kiln-dried lumber.